# How would I print this in PHP

Tags: php, arrays, class, object, echo

```
stdClass Object
(
    [entities] => stdClass Object
        (
            [urls] => Array
                (
                    [0] => stdClass Object
                        (
                            [url] => asdl;kfas.com
                            [expanded_url] => http://HOWDOIPRINTTHISURL.com
                            [display_url] => asdlkfsldfj.com
                        )

                )

        )

)
```

When I do print_r for my variable $fullurl I get the code above. How would I print the part that says 'http://HOWDOIPRINTTHISURL.com'? Thanks

Comment: `echo $object->entities->urls[0]->expanded_url`

Comment: It's written in the docs and pretty basic. Have you tried searching?

Comment: @Baba You don't have a class, but an object/instance stored in a variable. -0.1 for bad variable choice ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
print $fullurl->entities->urls[0]->expanded_url;
```